# JQuery Tablesorter special date

Tags: jquery, date, plugins, tablesorter

I have a table storing term information like these:

WINT 2018, SPR 2017,....

I want to sort the term column by addParser. The way I refer to is here:
https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers.html

My Plan is to change the term information to date, and sort the date.

My code is here:

```
$(function(){
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  // set a unique id
   id: 'term',
  is: function(s) {
    // return false so this parser is not auto detected
    return false;
  },
  format: function(s) {
    // format your data for normalization
   return s.toLowerCase()
      .replace(/wint /, /Jan 01, /)
      .replace(/sumr /, /Jul 01, /)
      .replace(/spr /, /Mar 01, /)
     .replace(/fall /, /Sep 01, /);
  },

  type: 'date'
}); 
    $(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
    headers: {      
      1: { sorter: "term" }
    }
    }
    );

});
```

The result is that the term column is frozen, while other columns are good.

My concerns are 2 points,
1. Is the replace format right? I could not find a replace example online.
2. Is the type : 'date' correct? Should it be text or numeric only?

Have anyone had similar experience? Any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found the type is only for numeric and text. I might be wrong, but I stick to the numeric and give up changing it to date.

The code is here, and it works for me.

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  // set a unique id
  id: 'term',
  is: function(s) {
    // return false so this parser is not auto detected
    return false;
  },
  format: function(s) {
    // format your data for normalization
    text = s.split(' '); 
    s=text[1] + text[0];
   return s.toLowerCase()
      .replace(/wint/, 1)
      .replace(/sumr/, 7)
      .replace(/spr/, 3)
     .replace(/fall/, 9);
  },
  // set type, either numeric or text
  type: 'numeric'
});         

    $(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
    headers: {

      1: { sorter: "term" }
    }
    }
    );
```

Thank you!

Comment: That should work. The parser is set to "numeric" and will sort parsed values as a number, but it's returning a string value; this still shouldn't cause any problems as long as the numbers are < 10. As for the online demo, check out the [grades parser code here](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers.html#demo).